# Parameterized Bit-fields in verilog

Tags: verilog, fpga, register-transfer-level

Is it possible to parameterize a bit-field in verilog? Essentially I want to use a parameter or alternative to define a bit-range. The only way I can think of doing this is with a `define as shown below but it seems like there should be a better way.

```
`define BITFIELD_SELECT 31:28
foo = bar[BITFIELD_SELECT]
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Parameters are nicer(safer) than defines since the namespace is not global to the project.  You should be able to do this with two parameters.

```
parameter BITFIELD_HIGH = 31;
parameter BITFIELD_LOW = 28;

assign foo = bar[BITFIELD_HIGH:BITFIELD_LOW];
```

Alternatively

```
parameter BITFIELD_HIGH = 31;
localparam BITFIELD_LOW = BITFIELD_HIGH-3;

assign foo = bar[BITFIELD_HIGH:BITFIELD_LOW];
```

Comment: Yeah I wasn't really a fan of the `define method, hence the question. Is this something you use in practice or is it just an answer to the questions asked?

Comment: I forget if I have ever defined the upper and lower bounds. Many times I have used a parameter to define the width of a vector. Ie: foo[(WIDTH-1):0]. It works great in practice and is very powerful combined with generate statements.

Comment: For some reason many developers are not aware of a convenient constant part select in Verilog-2001: assign foo = bar[HIGH -: SIZE];

Answer (score 0):

If you use macros (define) include the "`" when call the macro

```
`define BITFIELD_SELECT 31:28
foo = bar[`BITFIELD_SELECT]; // `BITFIELD_SELECT
```

Comment: This is not incorrect, however macros are not parameters. Would it not be easier to have a parameter WIDTH and then something like: `paramter WIDTH = 8; /*...*/ foo = bar[(WIDTH-1):0]`